# Dplyr - create a new column "group of numbers with decimal"

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe: Ratio2016

```
Name      Percapita
Alabama    0.60
Alaska     0.40
Arizona    0.22
California 1.53
```

To create a leaflet map basing the colors on the Percapita column, I want to create a new column percent_group 
 0.05-0.1
 0.1-0.5
 0.5-1.0
 1.0-1.5

My code :
  `

```
ratio2016<- ratio2016 %>% 
   mutate(percent_group = case_when(
    percapita %in% 0.05:0.1 ~ 0.05-0.1,
    percapita %in% 0.1:0.5 ~ 0.1-0.5,
    percapita %in% 0.5:1.0 ~ 0.5-1.0,
    percapita %in% 1.0:1.5 ~ 1.0-1.5,
    percapita %in% 1.5:2.0 ~ 1.5-2.0))
```

I obtain a column with only "NA"s
I have 2 rows with Nas.

Where is my mistake?
Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 1):

`%in%` is to check whether a value is the member of a set so it is the wrong thing to use here. You need `between()`.

```
ratio2016 <- ratio2016 %>% 
  mutate(percent_group = case_when(
    between(percapita, 0.05, 0.1) ~ "0.05-0.1",
    between(percapita, 0.1, 0.5) ~ "0.1-0.5",
    between(percapita, 0.5, 1) ~ "0.5-1.0",
    between(percapita, 1, 1.5) ~ "1.0-1.5",
    between(percapita, 1.5, 2) ~ "1.5-2.0"))
```

This will give you your column.

By the way, you can do it in less code with `cut()`:

```
ratio2016 %>% mutate(percent_group =
    cut(percapita, c(0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2), 
    labels = c("0.05-0.1","0.1-0.5", "0.5-1.0", "1.0-1.5", "1.5-2.0"))
  )
```